# System of Delay Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

In my differential equations course we are looking at systems of DDEs and I was wondering if there is a particular method that is used to solve these types of systems? One example that was given in class is the following;
$$\begin{align}v_1^\prime(t)&=\phi(t)v_1(t)\\  v_2^\prime(t)&=\alpha(v_1(t-1)-v_2(t-1)) \end{align}$$
Where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi(t)$ is some quasi-periodic function. Does an analytical solution exist? Or should I relay on numerical solutions as I have got here

[image]

Where x1 and x2 are v1 and v2 respectively, solutions to the above equation with $\phi(t)=1+2(t+\omega) (mod\ 1)$ for $w$ random.

Comment: It looks like you set the history as $v_1(t)=v_2(t)=1$ for $t<0$? And what does "$ω$ random" mean exactly?

Comment: @LutzLehmann In this case $\omega$ is a randomly drawn number between -1 and 1

Comment: But is it constant for the solution? It would be wrong if it is re-drawn at every evaluation of $\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first ODE we have

$$
v_1(t) = C_0 e^{\int_0^t \phi(\tau)d\tau}
$$

and the second after substitution

$$
v_2'(t) + \alpha v_2(t-1) = C_0 e^{\int_0^{t-1}\phi(\tau)d\tau}
$$

to solve this ODE you can use many numerical methods and also when $\phi(t)$ is a linear function like $b t$, the Laplace transform can provide algebraically suitable methods to make parametric considerations, as follows

$$
\alpha  \left(e^{-s} \left(\mathcal{L}_t[v_2(t)](s)\right)+e^{-s} \int_{-1}^0 e^{-s t} v_2(t) \, dt\right)+s \left(\mathcal{L}_t[v_2(t)](s)\right)-\frac{\sqrt{\pi
   } C_0 e^{\frac{(c-s)^2}{4 b}} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{c-s}{2 \sqrt{b}}\right)+1\right)}{2 \sqrt{b}}-v_2(0)=0
$$

or calling $V_2(s) = \mathcal{L}_t[v_2(t)](s)$

$$
V_2(s) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi } C_0 e^{\frac{(c-s)^2}{4 b}+s} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{c-s}{2 \sqrt{b}}\right)+1\right)-2 \sqrt{b} \left(\alpha  \int_{-1}^0
   e^{-s t} v_2(t) \, dt-e^s v_2(0)\right)}{2 \sqrt{b} \left(\alpha +e^s s\right)}
$$

now making some assumptions like $v_2(t) = 0$ for $-1\le t\le 0$ and using for $e^s$ the [Padé](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PadeApproximant.html) expansion we can proceed making stability considerations involving $\{\alpha, b, c\}$ as

$$
V_2(s) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi } C_0e^{\frac{(c-s)^2}{4 b}+s} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{c-s}{2 \sqrt{b}}\right)+1\right)}{2 \sqrt{b} \left(\alpha +e^s s\right)}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response Cesareo. I believe $v_1(t)=C_0e^{\int\phi(t)dt}$ but I see your process. Depending on the function $\phi$ this may not have any analytical solution correct? Like $\phi=\sin(\omega t)$ for some $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Now it is corrected.